# Hide H1 Element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to hide the `<h1>` element using plain javascript, not jQuery, without adding `id="whatever"` or `class="whatever"` to the  tag. Is this possible?

Why can't I just add id="whatever" to the  tag?
*I'm using a UIButton in xCode that when clicked, it injects javascript into a UIWebView. Inside that UIWebView is a H1 element that is on a website that I do not have access to to add `<h1 id="whatever">`. I hope it makes sense.*

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.display = "none";

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ubeduj/1/edit

Comment: @harsha: that won't work. `getElementsByTagName()` returns an `array` of elements. You forgot the index.

Comment: @Cerbrus : My Bad,sorry,totally missed it.Thank you :-)

Comment: Why not just use CSS? It’s faster and works everywhere. `<style>h1{display:none}</style>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Note that this will throw an error if there is no `H1` present. So be careful to use it in a global script.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) to hide the first `h1` on your page:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.display = "none";
//                                  ^ index 0, so that's the first `h` that's found.
```

Or to hide them all:

```
var headers = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
for (var i = 0, l = headers.length; i < l; i++; ) {
    headers[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Or even better yet, if you can modify the CSS:

```css
h1{
    display:none;
}
```

For the JavaScript solutions, please keep in mind that they will only work when the DOM has been loaded.

Add a `domready` event listener, like this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    // modify your DOM here.
});
```

Comment: `window.onload` is sooo slow, using it will guarantee a nasty page jump. Better to put the script below the `H1`.

Comment: @David: that would work too. Do you know if the `domready` event is any better?

Comment: @Cerbus yes, much better. `window.onload` also waits for all images in the document to finish loading. But placing script tags below the DOM elements that will be manipulated is always the fastest (but not always practical).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` method:

```
var h = context.getElementsByTagName('h1');
for (var i = h.length; i--; ) {
    h[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Where `context` is `document` or more specific parent node you want to search your headers within.

However there is better solution. You could add specific class to some parent node and hide child headers with CSS:

```
.without-headers h1 {display: none;}
```

Comment: OP stated he can't add `id`'s to his tags. I think it's safe to assume the same counts for classes: _"Inside that UIWebView is a H1 element that is on a website that I do not have access to"_

Comment: I meant that he could add class to a parent node via JS `context.className = "without-headers"`. Should have stated this.

Comment: That's a option, yea. Thanks for the clarification ^_^

Answer (score 1):

you can use [getElementsByTagName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp)

```
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")
```

But it will access all `h1` elements, so to be more specific access it by `index` like this

```
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 1):

just small change in dfsq's code

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

for (var i =0; i<h.length; i++) {
     document.getElementsByTagName('h1').item(i).style.display = 'none';
    }
```

Comment: Iterating over `document.getElementsByTagNameNS('h1')` _AND_ getting `document.getElementsByTagNameNS('h1')` in the _same_ for loop?
No, just... No. Also, why `getElementsByTagNameNS`? Why `item(i)`? It's like you're trying to avoid convention on purpose.